# Any tool/software equivalent of Microsoft "JouleMeter" in linux/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, power-management

"JouleMeter" is a tool from Microsoft for measuring power consumption by different processes on a windows machine.

Please tell me if there is any similar tool on linux for getting information of energy consumption by different processes and applications on linux machine. Also I am looking for an open-source solution.